# Customizing Jupyter Notebook cell behavior with code

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am writing and coming up with code illustrations in Jupyter Notebook. My use case then is to take the final code from certain code cells and put it in an HTML document. I have found a very good pipeline to use `pygments` package which highlights the code for me and puts it into proper HTML.

```py
from pygments import highlight
from pygments.lexers import PythonLexer
from pygments.formatters import HtmlFormatter

def PyHighlight(code):
    return highlight(code, PythonLexer(), HtmlFormatter())

PyHighlight("print('Hello world!')")
```

Output:

```
'<div class="highlight"><pre><span></span><span class="nb">print</span><span class="p">(</span><span class="s1">&#39;Hello world!&#39;</span><span class="p">)</span>\n</pre></div>\n'
```

But it's very tedious for me to convert each code cell into a string and then pass to the `PyHighlight` function and finally get the HTML.

Is there a way I can grab the content of each cell as string? Even better, can I trigger `PyHighlight` to run after every cell with the cell content as the argument to `PyHightlight` so I can just copy-paste the highlighted code HTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took some inspiration from the IPython documentation on [Custom Magic](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config/custommagics.html)

Define and register the following magic in a cell.

```py
from IPython.core.magic import  (Magics, cell_magic)

@magics_class
class MyMagics(Magics):

    @cell_magic
    def pygmented(self, line, cell):
        print(PyHighlight(cell))

get_ipython().register_magics(MyMagics)
```

After that, just add `%%pygmented` to the top of each cell, and after running the cell, the content of the cell would also be printed after all the highlighting (as asked in the question).